# Why ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup doesn't work?

Tags: c#

I was trying to "measure" stack depth. Why the following program doesn't print anything?

```
class Program
{
    private static int Depth = 0;

    static void A(object o) 
    {
        Depth++;
        A(o);
    }

    static void B(object o, bool e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Depth);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(A, B, null);
    }
}
```

Some answers simply include a quote from MSDN, like "Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default." Believe me, sometimes (when there is enough stack space) it can be cought, the following prints some number just fine:

```
class Program
{
    private static int depth = 0;

    static void A(object o)
    {
        depth++;
        if (Environment.StackTrace.Length > 8000)
            throw new StackOverflowException("Catch me if you can.");
        A(o);
    }

    static void B(object o, bool e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(depth);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(A, B, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Believe me, sometimes (when there is enough stack space) it can be cought"_; indeed. When you manually instantiate a `StackOverflowException` it is not considered a critical exception (a CSE: Corrupted State Exception) and it'll work just like any other exception. Same if you throw by-hand any other CSE. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/clr-inside-out-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to catch it, load it into another process (that calls-back to yours via remoting) and lets the miscreant code execute there. The other process may terminate, and you *could* get a neat SOE popping out the end of the pipe on your side - without the adverse effects of the rather inconvenient exception.

Note that a separate AppDomain in the same process won't cut it.

If you want to get the stack trace from an exception the following code will do you great justice:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Recurse(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex);
                // Go wild.
                Console.WriteLine(st.FrameCount);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Recurse(int counter)
        {
            if (counter >= 100)
                throw new Exception();
            Recurse(++counter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. This is cool, man. Could you also advice on how to get Depth value?

Comment: presto :)... added some stuff on the stack trace. Note that StackTrace is in System.Diagnostics, and is a slower critter (so use it wisely).

Comment: A little note on this old code from 10yrs ago: it does not measure stack depth, it measure the amount of nested calls. Since it is not tail-recursive, that part will work, but the stack depth (amount of bytes taken off the stack) depends on the amount of local variables, whether they are structs or not, the amount of arguments to the function and whether called functions are inlined by the JIT. Also, getting the stacktrace and framecount is very expensive.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your edit, I don't think user code throwing a StackOverflowException is the same as the CLR throwing it.

There's a bit of discussion about it [here](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/224083-help-me-understand-stackoverflowexception).

> Jeffrey's (Richter, author of [Applied Microsoft® .NET Framework Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735614229) ) comment applies to real stack overflows, i.e. to stack overflows
> that occur if your code contains an infinite recursion, something like:
>
> void MyMethod() { MyMethod(); }
>
> If you throw the
> StackOverflowException yourself, it
> will be handled like any other
> exception, and Jeffrey's comment does
> not apply.
>
> Also, Jeffrey's comment says: "if the
> stack overflow occurs WITHIN THE CLR
> ITSELF ...". So, if the .NET VM can
> detect the stack overflow "cleanly",
> i.e. without running ITSELF into a
> stack overflow, then you should get a
> StackOverflowException and your catch
> and finally blocks should execute as
> usual. But, in the tragic case where
> the VM ITSELF runs into a stack
> overflow, you won't be as lucky: the
> VM will not propagate a
> StackOverflowException (but crash in
> some other weird way) and your catch
> and finally blocks won't execute.
>
> Morale is: be careful with infinite
> recursion because you don't have a
> 100% guarantee that the VM will detect
> and signal them cleanly!
>
> Bruno.

Clarified who "Jeffrey" was since the OP was citing that book.

Comment: And you have a reference to support this claim?

Comment: By the way, ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedClenup doesn't even use a try/catch. It uses structured exception handling (SEH).

Comment: @prankster, even if it does throw an exception that same was as user code a SOE (or OutOfMemoryException, the other problem ex) leaves your stack in such a corrupted state that the runtime probably can't fix it... Which is why they changed it because 1.0 probably handled it unreliably.

Comment: Not sure why the 2nd linking is broken.  Looks fine in the preview.  2nd link was just link to book.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx):

> In prior versions of the .NET
>   Framework, your application could
>   catch a StackOverflowException object
>   (for example, to recover from
>   unbounded recursion). However, that
>   practice is currently discouraged
>   because significant additional code is
>   required to reliably catch a stack
>   overflow exception and continue
>   program execution.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch
>   block and the corresponding process is
>   terminated by default. Consequently,
>   users are advised to write their code
>   to detect and prevent a stack
>   overflow. For example, if your
>   application depends on recursion, use
>   a counter or a state condition to
>   terminate the recursive loop. Note
>   that an application that hosts the
>   common language runtime (CLR) can
>   specify that the CLR unload the
>   application domain where the stack
>   overflow exception occurs and let the
>   corresponding process continue. For
>   more information, see
>   ICLRPolicyManager Interface and
>   Hosting the Common Language Runtime.

Due to this fact I don't believe that you will be able to do what you want to do as the `StackOverflowException will terminate the process.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default