# Capture StackOverflow Exception information on user's PC

Tags: c#

A StackOverflow exception is occurring within my Winforms application (.NET v2) on a user's PC.  This exception is not caught by my application which is to be expected from the .NET documentation.

How can I get useful information to try and resolve this - firstly it would be good to find out the method causing this - is it possible to capture the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StackOverflowException may be caught by your code, but the runtime automatically re-throws it, so the end result is that the process is terminated.

Unless you're doing some heavy recursion a StackOverflowException is usually a sign of a bug. If you are doing a lot of recursion and need more stack space to handle it, you can set a bigger stack size by either changing the PE header of your executable or by creating a new thread using the constructor overload that takes stack space as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following post will be helpful.

[Why ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup doesn’t work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748573/why-executecodewithguaranteedcleanup-doesnt-work/748597)